# Make calls to async function to be executed sequentially in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to implement `send` function so that `calculate` will be executed **sequentially**, with **order** of calls preserved?

```
async function calculate(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value * value), 1)
  })
}

async function send(value) {
  return await calculate(value)
}
```

- Next call of `calculate` should not start until the previous call is finished.
- Calls to `calculate` should arrive in the exact same order.
- **Results** for `await` should be returned correctly.

It should work this way when the caller ignores result (we always return the result and don't care if it's used or not)

```
send(2)
send(3)
```

and for async calls too

```
;(async () => {
  console.log(await send(2))
  console.log(await send(3))
})()
```

P.S.

Why it's getting down-voted? It's a perfectly legitimate use case for a stateful remote service, where `calculate` will be the remote call. And you have to preserve the order because the remote service is stateful and results depends on the call order.

Comment: deleting your questions, then posting a new one, that has almost identical text, 10 minutes later, is not the way to go.

Comment: What you want to do is set up an asyncronous queue so that syncronous calls don't overlap each other.

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `calculate` at all, or why it needs a `setTimeout`.  But the behavior you're describing sounds like exactly what `await` does.  In your first example of calling `send` twice you're just not awaiting them.  Maybe you can put together a complete and runnable example demonstrating how you're handling your async operations that they should be awaited but aren't?

Comment: @David about not calling - please check the example, I updated it. `calculate` represents remote web service, it can be called in both ways - with `await` when we want to do something with the response and without the `await` when we just want to call it and ignoring the result.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin: *"and without the await"* - Regardless of whether you want to use the result or not, omitting the await specifically tells the code *not* to await the operation.  Are you really asking how to await an operation without awaiting it?

Comment: @David omitting `await` tells the **consumer code** how to execute the call. It does not however dictate how the **call itself internally should be executed**. Like - if some node.js process issues thousands parallel `sends` (without await) to database - I don't care if the node program will crash, but I do care to prevent the database to be hit by 1000 parallel requests. So I put this protection - no matter how `send` called - the database is protected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I set up async queues so that it processes things in order regardless of how they're called:

```
function calculate(value) {
  var reject;
  var resolve;
  var promise = new Promise((r, rr) => {
    resolve = r;
    reject = rr;
  })

  queue.add({
    value: value,
    resolve: resolve,
    reject: reject
  });

  return promise;
}

var calcluateQueue = {
  list: [], // each member of list should have a value, resolve and reject property
  add: function(obj) {
    this.list.push(obj); // obj should have a value, resolve and reject properties
    this.processNext();
  },
  processNext: async function() {
    if (this.processing) return; // stops you from processing two objects at once
    this.processing = true;
    var next = this.list.unshift(); // next is the first element on the list array
    if (!next) return;
    try {
      var result = await doSomeProcessing(next.value);
      next.resolve(result);
      this.processNext();
    } catch(e) {
      next.reject(e);
      // you can do error processing here, including conditionally putting next back onto the processing queue if you want to
      // or waiting for a while until you try again
      this.processNext();
    }    
  }
};
```

Comment: Please note: I just made this up. It may not be the best solution and you should test any implementation of anything you make based on this before using it.

Comment: thanks. Just wondering - what would happen if exception is thrown in `next.reject(e)` - is it possible to preserve the same behaviour as if there was no queue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.